# Background task that restarts parallel tasks in C#

Tags: c#, multithreading, parallel-processing, publish-subscribe

I have an application that creates a task(using task factory) which pings a queue URL every minute to check for connectivity. If the connectivity is established, it initiates three tasks using parallel.for() . These tasks subscribe to the queue. Once connected, the task(parent task) pings every 1 minute to check if connectivity still exists. In case there is a network issue or a connection breaks, the cancellation token is called for all the parallel tasks and they are restarted after the ping is successful.

This is my rather strange solution to the requirements that I need to fulfill which is as follows:
1. Create an app that subscribes to a queue. 
2. Make it have more than 1 consumer (multi threaded) - hence I use parallel.for()
3. Make sure the app restarts itself if it encounters any issue (hence the task that's created using the task factory which restarts the subscription )

Now this setup doesn't provide me the performance that I expect from a multi threaded app. Any suggestions ?

Comment: What performance are you getting and what do you expect? It sounds like most of the time is spent in sleep or i/o.

What does a profiler show?

Comment: "this setup doesn't provide me the performance that I expect from a multi threaded app" - You should only expect good results from CPU bound tasks. Your description talks about a lot of network calls - they aren't CPU bound. This code could be slower than using a single thread - but we wouldn't know because you haven't posted any actual code.

Comment: Messages are not consumed fast enough and pile up in the queue. Assuming a single thread app consumes 5 messages per second, an app with three threads consume only around 9 messages per second. Is there a better way of implementing this? The problem is that the incoming message rate is 28 per second